# Dark energy/matter warp drive not to be confused with Negative matter drive

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

While researching about different possible space-drives for my sci-fi universe I came across a Warp Drive theory that makes use of [Dark Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) and [Dark Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter). At first I believed them to be similar to [Alcubierre Warp Drives](https://phys.org/news/2017-01-alcubierre-warp.html) however, I found that dark matter, dark energy, and negative energy (exotic energy) are very different things. I tried to research it but, most everything I found did not specify how the engine would theoretically work. So my question is:

**How would a dark matter or dark energy warp drive theoretically work as compared to the Alcubierre Warp Drive?**

Comment: Are you OK with technobabble? Because we do not know what dark matter and energy *are*, so we can't have any real theories on how would they work.

Comment: There isn't much scientific knowledge on dark matter/energy, so this might be more suited for https://physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp_drive is sci-fi FTL, while https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy are hypothetical present physics phenomena. I think you need to specify more the premise.

Comment: @Snowshard I beg to disagree. A lot of theoretical papers have been written on the subject proposing different explanations for dark matter and dark energy; however, his question is purely for worldbuilding. He simply requires someone versed in this end of SciFi and Theoretical Physics.

Comment: @adonies In 1994 The Mexican physcist Miguel Alcubierre came up with a formal physics explanation for the warp drive. His proposal and subsequent derivatives are referred to as Alcubierre Warp Drives.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify OP's intent. I've performed research in precisely what OP is describing, so I know what he's asking for and have an answer prepared.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2013 film **Space Pirate Captain Harlock**, the protagonist's ship runs on "dark matter". It is never explained in any technical way since it is supposed to be a spooky alien technology (side effects include bringing people back from the dead). Compare to a *Phantom Drive* or a portal powered by a graveyard.

In astrophysics, dark matter is a placeholder for something we don't understand. Our galaxy (for instance) moves in a way that suggests it weighs more than it should, based on what we can detect. That discrepancy could be solved if there is more there there, hence "dark" or "unknown" matter. In another era it might have been called "X matter".

[image]

Comment: Likewise, Dark Energy is a placeholder for something we don't understand; the luminosity discrepancy for distant Supernova. The Answer for the OP is, make up whatever you want, nobody can prove you wrong. Probably Dark Matter and Dark Energy will both evaporate with a better model of physics, one that comports with the Standard Model of quantum physics and General Relativity, and explains them. Currently physics is confused; it has no particle candidates or testable theories for what Dark Matter or Dark Energy can be; their explanation demands a new and improved theory of physics!